# uber api: error: "invalid_scope" with "Business.Receipt" - [uber-api]

Tags: uber-api

We have a problem with scope "Business.Receipt" which allowed us to get receipt details for requests made by our app. And the Scope stopped working returning "error":"invalid_scope”. We really need help please!

I work to a company that hires an api uber integration to control the runs and revenue of its employees. But when making a call in the api using “https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token” an "error" error is returned: "invalid_scope".

We provide the authentication correctly and the scope on the dashboard is correctly configured as well as the permission grants.

An integration always worked, but this scope error started to occur. We follow documents https://developer.uber.com/docs/businesses/references/api/v2/token-post to request receipts and the error below is returned. I emphasize that the scope on the dashboard is correctly configured as well as the permission grants.

"error":"invalid_scope”

Comment: Having the same problem.
Our team tried to contact uber support across multiple channels and we haven't had any feedback for months.